# How not to expire user session cakephp

Tags: php, session, cakephp, usersession

I'm developing an application in CakePHP for monitoring and I do not want my user session to expire because user needs to needs to see the control panel frequently even if he is not using the application.

I have found many ways but I do not know which is the best one...

What do you recommend?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: Have you tried to change session.timeout in core.php

Comment: Well, I haven't tried anything yet. I have been reading too much things about how to set a specific time, but I don't want it, I don't want to set 12312312312231 minutes for example, I just want to block the expiring of user session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to config/core.php file , set session settings like this

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'Session.timeout' => '12312312312231'
    ));
```

Now you can change session timeout as you like. 
If you not set session timeout time then you need to access your after login function through ajax request in a time period.You need to run a ajax request in 1 minute interval to your after login any controller function. like this 
create a function `ajax_request()` in your after login controller. Now

```
setInterval(function(){
//Your ajax code
},1000);
```

When ajax request goes to your controller function then auth component always extends expiry time.

Comment: Well, I have found a way where you do not have to call an ajax request. If you set the timeout like this: `Configure::write('Session', array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'Session.timeout' => 0
    ));` It makes the session "infinite"

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->Session->destroy();
```

The `destroy` method will delete the session, cookie and all session data stored in temporary file system.

User to remove, use better `delete`.

```
$this->Session->delete('User');
```